# javascript - create an object containing objects based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, angular.js

Based on JSON data I receive, I am trying to track a team's home and away games. The JSON data is stored in `$scope.gameSchedules` and has "team1" for home games and "team2" for away games. I need to initially create an object with each team's name and the only way I can get all the teams' names is via the "team1/team2" values in the initial JSON data (thus the two loops below). This was my working solution to create an object that looks like this (called homeVsAwayGames):

[image]

The initial JSON data response:
[image]

Here is my code. Is there a better way to do it, or more concise, perhaps using underscore (not necessary)? I feel that perhaps I have too many lines of code and it can be refactored:

```
 $scope.getSchedules = function() {
        return TeamsScheduleService.getTeamSchedules().then(function(response) {
            $scope.gamesSchedule = response.data.games;
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("there was an error getting the schedules");
        })
    }
    $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules = {};
    $scope.getSchedules().then(trackHomeVsAway).then(function(){
        console.log($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules);
    })
    //TODO: ng-repeat over the homeVsAwaySchedules Object to display in the view. 

    function trackHomeVsAway() {
        //initialize homeVsAwaySchedules object in separate loop for efficiency and readability, instead of trying to initialize + tally at the same time.
        $scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
          var homeTeam = gameData.team1;
          var awayTeam = gameData.team2;
            if (homeTeam) {
                if (!$scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]) {
                    $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam] = {
                        "Home Games": 0,
                        "Away Games": 0
                    };
                }
            }
            if (awayTeam) {
                if (!$scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]) {
                    $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam] = {
                        "Home Games": 0,
                        "Away Games": 0
                    };
                }
            }
        })

        $scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
          var homeTeam = gameData.team1;
          var awayTeam = gameData.team2;
            if (homeTeam) {
                if ($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]) {
                    $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]["Home Games"]++;
                }
            }
            if (awayTeam) {
                if ($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]) {
                    $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]["Away Games"]++;
                }
            }
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over how the initial data structure is injected into $scope?  In other words why go through all this is you can start with a better data structure?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, no. It's from a third-party. I'm getting json response from a third party API and I have to change it to make it easy to use NG repeat on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could *dry up* this code by adding some helper functions.

For example instead of this:

> ```
> $scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
>   var homeTeam = gameData.team1;
>   var awayTeam = gameData.team2;
>     if (homeTeam) {
>         if (!$scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]) {
>             $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam] = {
>                 "Home Games": 0,
>                 "Away Games": 0
>             };
>         }
>     }
>     if (awayTeam) {
>         if (!$scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]) {
>             $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam] = {
>                 "Home Games": 0,
>                 "Away Games": 0
>             };
>         }
>     }
> })
> ```

You could write using a helper function:

```
$scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
    function checkTeam(team) {
        if (team) {
            if (!$scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[team]) {
                $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[team] = {
                    "Home Games": 0,
                    "Away Games": 0
                };
            }
        }
    }
    checkTeam(gameData.team1);
    checkTeam(gameData.team2);
})
```

Similarly, instead of this:

> ```
> $scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
>   var homeTeam = gameData.team1;
>   var awayTeam = gameData.team2;
>     if (homeTeam) {
>         if ($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]) {
>             $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[homeTeam]["Home Games"]++;
>         }
>     }
>     if (awayTeam) {
>         if ($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]) {
>             $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[awayTeam]["Away Games"]++;
>         }
>     }
> })
> ```

You could write using a helper function:

```
$scope.gamesSchedule.forEach(function(gameData) {
    function updateTeamSchedule(team, games) {
        if (team) {
            if ($scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[team]) {
                $scope.homeVsAwaySchedules[team][games]++;
            }
        }
    }
    updateTeamSchedule(gameData.team1);
    updateTeamSchedule(gameData.team2);
})
```